# SfB 2016 / Lync 2013 SDK App sharing broken

Tags: wpf, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

we use the [Lync 2013 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824) with SfB 2016 in UI suppression in order to ship an WPF app with custom support integration.

Roughly about summer 2017 the app sharing broke and we were unable to recover the functionality.

We suppose this is related to either some Windows Update / SP or SfB Client/Server Update and/or configuration.

Sharing apps/desktop useing the SfB client without UI suppression works without any problems.

Even the official example on how to use the app sharing does not work for us anymore: [Lync 2013 SDK: Share resources in UI suppression](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Lync-Client-2013-SDK-CU2-02f9292e)

The app sharing works outbound to a SfB client without UI suppression, so only the incoming display seems to be broken, regardless of the source (be it a SfB w/o UI suppression or our own app).

The VideoWindow is rendered, height / width are correctly transmitted, but the drawn rectangle remains blank / grey.

Is there any possibility to recover this function? Or at least some information why or what broke this function?

Clients were tested to be broken in Windows 10 Pro x64, Anniversary and Fall Creators Update, SfB Client 2016 MSO 16.0.4318.1000.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following references to the sample app you mentioned.

- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- System.Xaml
- UIAutomationProvider
- WindowsBase
- WindowsFormsIntegration

Maybe they're not all required, but I discovered that they solved the white/blank or black screen that you see when running the sample app without any changes.

I discovered this by adding an ElementHost to the app, which wasn't required, but it automatically added these references and it fixed your issue.

Note that in my case, adding these references introduced DPI scaling issues in the app, so you might want to fix those.